# Method will not replace last element in a list

Tags: java

I have a method to replace elements in a linked  list. It was working fine however I noticed that the last element in the list does not get replaced. I wanted to know where am I going wrong?

```
public class ListOfNVersion03PartB
{   
    private int thisNumber;              // the number stored in this node
    private ListOfNVersion03PartB next;  // forms a linked list of objects

    private final int nodeID;            // a unique ID for each object in the list

    private static int nodeCount = 0;    // the number of list objects that have been created

    public ListOfNVersion03PartB(int num)
    {
        thisNumber = num;
        next = null;

        ++nodeCount;
        nodeID = nodeCount;

    } 

public int replaceOnce(int replaceThis, int withThis)
    {        
       int count = 0;

        if(   (next!= null) && (thisNumber == replaceThis)   ){
            thisNumber= withThis;
            return count =1;
        }        
        if(   (next!= null) && (thisNumber != replaceThis)   ){
            return next.replaceOnce(replaceThis,withThis);
        }

        else
            return count;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to loop over the node and compare with the value and replace if you found a node with `replaceThis`  value

```
    public int replaceOnce(int replaceThis, int withThis) {
        ListOfNVersion03PartB current = this;
        int count = 0;
        while (current != null) {
            if (current.thisNumber == replaceThis) {
                current.thisNumber = withThis;
                count++;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
        return count;
    }
```